# Create a non admin area form to update user form

Tags: 7, forms, users

I'm trying to see if there's an example of a form that isn’t in the admin area and is used to update user details.

Is it possible to create this type of form? Where can I find such an example?

Comment: probably if you have permission to edit other users you can access form of edit user profile etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Drupal core user module, is generates the forms for account editing. Specifically, [`user_profile_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_profile_form/7.x), [`user_account_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7.x), & [`user_profile_form_submit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/user_profile_form_submit/7.x) will give you an example of an user-accessible form that updates a user account.